# Access VBA Update query with if statement

Tags: ms-access

I have a table called **process** which has the following structure and data:

```
stageID    Dia   Thk   Length Time     TAG
---------  ----  ----  ------ ------  ------
P3         10    4      7.5            -1
P4         10    4.3    7.5            -1
```

I want to use an `UPDATE` query that will update the `Time` field where `TAG = -1` and `DIA > 10` or `DIA < 2`. How do I do this?

Comment: I've edited your question, but it's being peer-reviewed at the moment. You have not said what you want to be put in the `Time` field should the criteria you specify are met.

Comment: maybe start with how to write a question :). help here > http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I'm only answering this because I think you need some guidance, and it can be in the form of an answer.

### First of all

The sample data you gave us **doesn't even fit the criteria of your `WHERE` clause!**
You're saying, `Update MyTable Set Time = SOMETHING WHERE TAG = -1 AND Dia > 10 OR TAG = -1 AND Dia < 2`.

In your sample data, I don't seee any records that even fit that criteria? Did you mean `Dia >= 10`?

### The query:

```
UPDATE Raju 
SET Raju.[Time] = 1111111
WHERE (((Raju.TAG)=-1) 
               AND ((Raju.Dia)>10)) 
OR (((Raju.TAG)=-1) 
               AND ((Raju.Dia)<2));
```

In the query, replace `Raju` with your table name and set the value of `Time` appropriately.

We are saying:

1. Update the table (I used Raju as my table name)
2. Set the `Time` field = to `1111111` - set it to whatever you want.
3. ONLY Update the `Time` field WHERE
4. `TAG = -1 AND Dia > 10` **OR**
5. `TAG = -1 AND Dia < 2`

Comment: Consider `WHERE Raju.TAG= -1 AND (Raju.Dia>10 OR Raju.Dia<2)` or maybe `WHERE Raju.TAG= -1 AND NOT (Raju.Dia BETWEEN 2 AND 10)`

Comment: Very true! There are definitely more ways than my solution to write it. I did think it was valuable to kind of spell them out as 'vanilla' as possible to get the point across. But, as always, you hit the nail on the head!

Comment: Seemed to me your version of the `WHERE` may be the most appropriate for the OP.  I offered alternatives for other readers.  Cheers.